# How to get an application to use a local branch version of Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, rubygems

Let's say I want to add some new features to Rails. According to the [Rails Guide on how to contribute to Rails](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/contributing_to_ruby_on_rails.html), I should clone the main repository, create a branch, then make my changes in that branch.

My question is: after I've done all of that, how do I go about testing my changes in an actual Rails application? That is, how do I get a Rails application running on my machine to use the Rails code from my branch rather than the Rails code installed on my system?

The simplest approach I can think of is to simply replace the "rails" folder in my gems folder with the code from my branch, but it seems like there should be a cleaner way to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using bundler, just point to your modified version in your Gemfile by specifying either the path of the gem on the filesystem or your forked git repo. Like this:

gem 'rails', :path => '/full/path/to/mofidied/rails'

or for git:

gem 'rails', :git => git://github.com/github_user/your_rails.git

Comment: This only works on existing rails apps though, if you want to create a new app you have to specify the version. I'm not sure of a way to specify the source in a similar way though.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the minor revision number and install it in your gems folder you can specify that new version when you create a new app

`rails _3.0.x_ new newappname`